# Initializing Gridfs returns TypeError: string is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, gridfs, monk

I'm trying to write an uploaded file (such as an image) to a mongodb database. However when I try to initialize the gridfs-stream I get a Type Error. Here's my code:

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');

router.post('/createpost', cpUpload, function(req,res) {
  var db = req.db;

  var gfs = Grid(db,mongo);

  var file = req.file;

  var fileId = new ObjectId();

  var writestream = gfs.createWriteStream({
    filename: file.originalname,
    mode: 'w',
    content_type: file.mimetype,
    metadata: req.body.postText,
  });
  fs.createReadStream(file.path).pipe(writestream);

  writestream.on('close', function(file) {
    res.send("Succcess!");
    fs.unlink(file.path,function(err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("Error: ", err);
        console.log("DELETED: ", file.path);
      }
  });
 });


});
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with me calling `db` as `req.db` but I make the db accessible to the router file with this code in app.js

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var monk = require('monk');
var db = monk('localhost:27017/test-api');

app.use(function(req,res,next) {
  req.db = db;
  req.mongo = mongo;
  next();
});
```

Comment: My answer below fixed the `string is not a function` error but I am still not getting this code to work. I posted another question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31528119/gridfs-createwritestream-not-working-with-monk-for-mongodb)

Answer (score 0):

I had the incorrect syntax for `var Grid = require('gridfs-stream');` very easy fix.